# How to compile qt5.13.2 that include specific module called "QtGraphicalEffects " for linux sytem?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, cross-compiling

I'm building a project that could run on both windows and linux,and when I finish my debug on windows , I find that my linux qt cross-compile chain do not have the shader module called QtGraphicalEffects but windows has it.
[image]

[image]

and i try to compile qt by add params ,but i can't find the param of qt compile configure,can anyone help? thanks a lot
Here is my configure param , i hide the path of some  libs' reliance:
./configure -prefix /home/qt5.13.2-x86_64-noicu -release -xplatform linux-g++-64 -confirm-license -opensource -no-icu -ssl -openssl -openssl-runtime -no-fontconfig -no-harfbuzz -qt-zlib -qt-xcb -qpa xcb -feature-thread -no-opengl -skip qtlocation -nomake examples -nomake tests -recheck-all XKBCOMMON_PREFIX="${}" XKBCOMMON_LIBS="-lxkbcommon" XKBCOMMON_X11_PREFIX="${}" XKBCOMMON_X11_LIBS="-lxkbcommon-x11 -Wl,-rpath-link=${}/lib:${}/lib:${}/lib" XCB_PREFIX="${}" XCB_LIBS="-lxcb -Wl,-rpath-link=${CONAN_BUILD_DIRS_LIBXAU}/lib" XCB_XKB_PREFIX="${}" XCB_XKB_LIBS="-lxcb-xkb -Wl,-rpath-link=${}/lib" -I"${}/include" -I"${}/include" CUPS_PREFIX="${}" CUPS_LIBS="-lcups -Wl,-rpath-link=${}/lib" -I"${}/include" -I"${}/include" OPENSSL_PREFIX="${}" OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssl -lcrypto -Wl,-rpath-link=${}/lib" -I"${}/include""

Comment: Are you cross-compiling from Linux to Windows, or vice versa?

Comment: no,i am just compiling for linux only . actually, i'm trying use qml to achieve similar visual effect, and my linux cross-building chain is compiled by qt-everywhere-src-5.13.2.tar.xz, as the pic 2 showed : there is not a dictionary called QtGraphicalEffects as my windows qt libs

Comment: Cross-compilation is using one OS to produce applications for a different OS. If you're compiling on Linux for Linux, that's not cross-compilation.

Comment: yes , you are right . And I am using three different architectures of Linux systems: aarch64 ,mip64el and x86_64.  my  " cross building" is build aarch mipsel at a x86 server . thank you for pointing the shortcomings of the problem description. and maybe you could tell me how can i compile qt with "QtGraphicalEffects "? that will help a lot

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Point is, you don't even describe a real problem, just a folder that's only on one OS. What problems does that cause? Concerning the code inside, is it perhaps even documented as not portable? What errors do you get when crosscompiling? What would be a [mcve] for this?

Comment: I'm sure that I've clearly described my question: why qt5.13.2 compiled in linux do not have the module  which is contained in a qt deploy package

Comment: *"my " cross building" is build aarch mipsel at a x86 server"* Ah, got it. I would start by comparing Qt versions on Windows vs Linux. Also with what command are you building on Linux? Please begin replies with `@username`, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: @圣黑猫 thank you for your guidance , i'm a new one here.... i will edit the question description with my configure parameter

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I would nitpick there... cross-compilation supposes any kind of platform hop, platform includes architecture, OS type, kernel version or run-time library change (libc version in our case), significant enough to cause a need in a different executable. Oh, and we also have a Canadian cross.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yeah, I realized my mistake after OP explained what they do. Assumed they didn't know what cross-compilation means, and wanted to give a simple definition without bothering them with the details.

Answer (score 0):

`configure` reports what modules will not be compiled and why, it also saves `configure.log` with all relevant information. It may skip optional targets due to missing dependencies.

You can download sources for this module and compile and install it separatly [qtgraphicaleffects-everywhere-src-5.13.2.tar.xz](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.13/5.13.2/submodules/qtgraphicaleffects-everywhere-src-5.13.2.tar.xz)

Comment: thanks,not the best resolution but could work